# Raster calculator - set default output path - QGIS 3.4.6

Tags: qgis-3, raster-calculator, file-path

Raster calculator: How can I set the default output folder?
By default it's set to "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin"
I'm using QGIS 3.4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *Python Console* and enter the following with your defined path:

```
QSettings().setValue("/RasterCalculator/lastOutputDir", "myOutputPath")
```

This will remain the default path even after you restart QGIS.

Comment: Don't forget to include double backslashes in "myOutputPath" e.g. C:\\temp\\rasters